# Three20 TTPhotoViewController detailedView photo overlap problem

Tags: iphone, three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

In my application, I'm using three20 library's photoViewController. The photos in photo detailedview are overlapping. Specifically, if there are three photos, 1st and 3rd look fine, but 2nd photo is overlapped by 1st.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Line 135 of TTPhotoView.m is
self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

It should be
self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: really helpfull and image that doesn't overlap

Answer (score 2):

Change to YES this:

```
self.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

file TTPhotoView.m line 63